# I want to play next song automatically in media player

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

When I click on any song from playlist **first time** it plays next song, this problem has only happened for the first time on second or more click on any song from the playlist it working fine.

But the major problem has, it unable to play next song after the end of any song anytime.

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
                // play next song
                if(listView_click_arg2 < (songPath.length - 1)){
                    listView_click_arg2=listView_click_arg2+1;
                }
                else{
                    // play first song
                    listView_click_arg2=0;
                }
            try {
                playSong(songPath[listView_click_arg2]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
    startTime=0;
    finalTime=0;
    oneTimeOnly=0;
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer=null;
    mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: This code will be working fine if we put setOnCompletionListener() just after the setDataSource() in playSong function.

Answer (score 0):

I found you have a problem because of mediaPlayer.reset() function. It says

**When a MediaPlayer object is just created using new or after reset() is called, it is in the Idle state; and after release() is called, it is in the End state. Between these two states is the life cycle of the MediaPlayer object.**

Please go through this link. There is a nice Flow chart: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

[image]

I belive, after you remove mediaPlayer.reset() inside the onCompletionListener body, it will get solved.

Comment: I remove mediaPlayer.reset() method, but the problem still persists as same as previous.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding release(). It looks like a out of memory issue.

```
private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
    startTime=0;
    finalTime=0;
    oneTimeOnly=0;
    // changing the state of mediaPlayer inside its own callback is a bad practice.
    //mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release(); // <<------ Add this before reference is gone.
    mediaPlayer=null;
    mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```